# how to remove all the "() and text within it" in Java String

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to ask about the deletion of parenthesis and text within them in Java String. For example, I have

```
String str = "I am a new (Software) Engineer"
```

Now the question is, how to remove the substring "(software)" here without using

```
str.replace("(software)", "")
```

because may be in next string I would get "I am a new (Electrical) Engineer" or  "(Mechanical") or something like that.

So how can I do this, I think one way is to get the index of "(" and ")" and removing/replacing them by using that indices but I hope there will be some shorter way to do this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use regex to match anything in brackets:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\) ?", "");
```

Note that the brackets must be escaped, and that the escape character `\` itself must be escaped in the String, hence the *double* backslashes.

The term `.*?` is a *reluctant* match, which means that it won't skip all the way to the last bracket in case there are two bracketed terms in the input ie "a (foo) b (bar) c" would become "a c" if `.*` was used, because it would consume everything from the first open bracket to the last close bracket.

I added an optional space at the end so you won't be left with two adjacent spaces once you remove the intervening term.

Comment: This is not ideal: outside `(a text (in another) parenthesis)` will remove only `(a text (in another)`.

Comment: @Dariusz yes - it does not cater for nested brackets. Such an occurrence was not implied by OP. let's see if OP can clarify this for us.

Comment: Works perfectly for single parenthesis set.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the most efficient and foolproof way would be to go through the entire String and check for brackets. It would require only a single sweep.

You would also have to keep track of the amount of parenthesis opened and closed, to make sure the algorithm is correct for sentences like `outside (a text (in another) parenthesis) outside again` which should result in `outside  outside again`.

A code which does more or less that.

```
public class RemoveParenthesis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int open = 0;
        int closed = 0;
        boolean changed = true;
        int startIndex = 0, openIndex = -1, closeIndex = -1;
        String text = "outside (a text (in another) parenthesis) outside again";
        System.out.println("before: " + text);

        while (changed) {
            changed = false;
            for (int a = startIndex; a < text.length(); a++) {
                if (text.charAt(a) == '(') {
                    open++;
                    if (open == 1) {
                        openIndex = a;
                    }
                } else if (text.charAt(a) == ')') {
                    closed++;
                    if (open == closed) {
                        closeIndex = a;
                        text = text.substring(0, openIndex)
                                + text.substring(closeIndex + 1);
                        changed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (open == 0)
                        startIndex++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("after: " + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: So better use to stack for this purpose

Comment: Doesn't work `a {b} c {d}` returns `a` instead of `a c`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String removeBracketContents(String response) {
        char ch;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        System.out.println("before removeBracketContents: " + response);
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            ch = response.charAt(i);
            switch (ch) {
            case '(':
                stack.push(new Character(ch));
                break;

            case ')':
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                    return response;
                else
                    stack.pop();
                break;
            default:
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                    sb.append(ch);
             break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("after removeBracketContents: " + sb.toString());
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Missing ) at end");
            System.out.println("after removeBracketContents: " + response);
            return response;
        } else {
            System.out.println("after removeBracketContents: " + sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```